# Can this be parsed by a LALR(1) parser?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, lalr, shift-reduce-conflict

I am writing a parser in Bison for a language which has the following constructs, among others:

- self-dispatch: [`identifier` `arguments`]
- dispatch: [`expression` . `identifier` `arguments`]
- string slicing: `expression`[`expression`,`expression`] - similar to Python.

`arguments` is a comma-separated list of expressions, which can be empty too.  All of the above are expressions on their own, too.
My problem is that I am not sure how to parse both `[method [other_method]]` and `[someString[idx1, idx2].toInt]` or if it is possible to do this at all with an LALR(1) parser.

To be more precise, let's take the following example: `[a[b]]` (call method `a` with the result of method `b`).  When it reaches the state `[a` . `[b]]` (the lookahead is the second `[`), it won't know whether to reduce `a` (which has already been reduced to `identifier`) to `expression` because something like `a[b,c]` might follow (which could itself be reduced to `expression` and continue with the second construct from above) or to keep it `identifier` (and shift it) because a list of `arguments` will follow (such as `[b]` in this case).

Is this shift/reduce conflict due to the way I expressed this grammar or is it not possible to parse all of these constructs with an LALR(1) parser?

And, a more general question, how can one prove that a language is/is not parsable by a particular type of parser?

Comment: "How can one prove that something is/is not parsable by a particular type of parser?" Please be explicit about "something". There is [a difference between languages and grammars](/a/476009/824425) (that answer should answer your last question regarding LL(1), but generalises to pretty much any parser type). What you're specifying here are some features of the language, but without a grammar, there really isn't much to talk about.

Comment: @Rhymoid I edited it to be clearer.  I was asking about languages, not grammars.  And I don't think it is necessary to add the grammar I wrote as part of the question, just because I am asking if the *language* (some of its constructs, to be more precise) is parsable by LALR(1), not the grammar.

Comment: @EJP I have.  I wrote a grammar which has a shift/reduce conflict described above.  I thought a lot how to avoid it and I failed.  And now I was thinking that maybe the language itself, due to these constructs, cannot be parsed with a LALR(1) parser, irrespective of the way you write the grammar.

Comment: In that case: there is no general way to determine that. It also can't be determined for this particular case, not in the least because you have not specified your language (which would be easy to specify as a grammar, be it LALR(1) or not; think of it as a [MCVE](/help/mcve) for this type of questions).

Comment: @Rhymoid I specified just enough of the language's grammar one needs to know in order to be helpful.  If you don't know or don't want to be, feel free to ignore this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your grammar is unambiguous (which the part you describe appears to be) then your best bet is to specify a `%glr-parser`. Since in most cases, the correct parse will be forced after only a few tokens, the overhead should not be noticeable, and the advantage is that you do not need to complicate either the grammar or the construction of the AST.

The one downside is that bison cannot verify that the grammar is unambiguous -- in general, this is not possible -- and it is not easy to prove. If it turns out that some input is ambiguous, the GLR parser will generate an error, so a good test suite is important.

Proving that the language is not LR(1) would be tricky, and I suspect that it would be impossible because the language probably is *recognizable* with an LALR(1) parser. (Impossible to tell without seeing the entire grammar, though.) But parsing (outside of CS theory) needs to create a correct parse tree in order to be useful, and the sort of modifications required to produce an LR grammar will also modify the AST, requiring a post-parse fixup. The difficultly in creating a correct AST spring from the difference in precedence between

```
a[b[c],d]
```

and

```
[a[b[c],d]]
```

In the first (subset) case, `b` binds to its argument list `[c]` and the comma has lower precedence; in the end, `b[c]` and `d` are sibling children of the slice. In the second case (method invocation), the comma is part of the argument list and binds more tightly than the method application; `b`,  `[c]` and `d` are siblings in a method application. But you cannot decide the shape of the parse tree until an arbitrarily long input (since `d` could be any expression).

That's all a bit hand-wavey since "precedence" is not formally definable, and there are hacks which could make it possible to adjust the tree. Since the LR property is not really composable, it is really possible to provide a more rigorous analysis. But regardless, the GLR parser is likely to be the simplest and most robust solution.

One small point for future reference: CFGs are not just a programming tool; they also serve the purpose of clearly communicating the grammar in question. Nirmally, if you want to describe your language, you are better off using a clear CFG than trying to describe informally. Of course, meaningful non-terminal names will help, and a few examples never hurt, but the essence of the grammar is in the formal description and omitting that makes it harder for others to "be helpful".